# Select multiple values during insert data in sqlserver db against datagridview 1 row

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have three tables Product Purchase and Sale in sqlserver.
No i want to insert data in Sale tables.

Purchase table

[image]

Sale Form[image]

Sale Table

[image]

I want to get Pur_Invoice_No and Batch_No from Purchase table where sale quantity is greater than 0 and till sum against each Item_Code and Each Datagridview row during insert query in sale table using datagridview sale form. so i am using given below query which is not help me to resolve this issue.given below query is generating double values error.

```
try
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");
            conn.Open();

                SqlCommand commandd = new SqlCommand("Select max(Sale_Invoice_No) from Sale", conn);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()))
            {
                InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(1);

            }
            else
            {
                int tig =Convert.ToInt32( 1);

                InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(commandd.ExecuteScalar()) +tig;
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in saved.dataGridView1.Rows)
            {


                if (row.IsNewRow) continue;


                SqlConnection cons = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into Sale (Sale_Invoice_No,Payment_Type_ID,Customer_ID,Sale_Reference,Sale_Remarks,Item_Code,Item_Sale_Quantity,Item_Unit_RetailPrice,Sale_Item_Discount,Item_Discount_Amount,Item_Payable_Amount,Cash_Received,Return_Amount,Login_ID,User_ID,Item_Pur_InvoiceNo,Sale_Entry_Date)Values ('" + InvoiceNo + "','" + saved.comboBox1.SelectedValue + "','" + saved.comboBox2.SelectedValue + "','" + saved.textBox3.Text + "','" + saved.textBox4.Text + "','" + row.Cells[6].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[1].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[2].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[3].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[4].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + row.Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue + "','" + saved.textBox10.Text + "','" + saved.textBox11.Text + "','" + saved.comboBox3.SelectedValue + "','" + this.comboBox2.SelectedValue + "',(Select DISTINCT Pur_Invoice_No IN (Select DISTINCT Pur_Invoice_No from Purchase where Purchase.Item_Code ='" + row.Cells[6].EditedFormattedValue + "')),  GetDate())", cons);

                cons.Open();


                using (cons)
                {

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Invoice successfully Saved");
```

Can any body help me.

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is a textbook example of sql injection. As for your actual issue at hand here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If you really want to create the insert Statement in the application instead of using for example a stored procedure in SQL-Server you should first write the Statement inside of SSMS until it works fine. After that you can implement it in your application. But take care of SQL injection.

Comment: Seeing "SqlConnection" in the same method/class as "MessageBox.Show" makes my eyes hurt.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx